# TypeError: mongoose.model() is not a function in Nextjs with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am creating E-commerce app with Nextjs and using Mongoose in that app, in that app
i have this productSchema (models/Product):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    desc: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    size: { type: String },
    color: { type: String },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    availableQty: { type: Number, required: true },
    img: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

This is getProducts api (api/getProducts):

```
import Product from "../../models/Product";
import connectDb from "../../middleware/mongoose";
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  let products = await Product.find();
  res.status.json({ products });
};

export default connectDb(handler);
```

This is mongoose.js file (middleware/mongoose):

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectDb = (handler) => async (req, res) => {
  if (mongoose.connections[0].readyState) {
    return handler(req, res);
  }
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
  return handler(req, res);
};

export default connectDb;
```

when i open api/getProducts in the browser , i am gettting the Error :
TypeError: mongoose.model() is not a function.

How can i fix this? what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**There are two fields with the same name, "title" in the schema.** Try changing the name so there are no two fields with the same schema. The program should work now. I ran the model file with the change I suggested, and I didn't get the error.